# How to pass a file through multiple api in .net

Tags: rest, web, sharepoint, .net-core, download

I'm trying to download a file from Sharepoint using a REST API. Because my app is written in .Net Core, and the CSOM library doesn't support it, I've made a "sharepoint proxy" in .Net Framework, which is a single app hosted on Azure.
Now I have a problem, while trying to download a file. I send a request from Postman to my app in .Net Core, which send another request to the sharepoint proxy, which (at last) send a GET request to Sharepoint REST API. In result, I become in Sharepoint proxy a Stream from sharepoint REST API, which I try to forward back to my app. I have no idea, which format should I use to send the file. I tried WebStream, FileStream and byte[], but in each case I got an unreadable file.

**Download method in .Net Core App**

```cs
       public async Task<Stream> DownloadFile(SharePointFileUrl spInfo)
       {
           var restUrl = $"{siteUrl}/downloadFile";

           using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
           {
               var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(spInfo), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
               var webResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(restUrl, content);

               return await webResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
           }
       }
```

**Endpoint in Sharepoint proxy**

```cs
        public byte[] DownloadFile([FromBody] SharePointFileUrl fileInfo)
        {
            return _spService.DownloadFile(fileInfo.FileUrl);
        }
```

**Download method in Sharepoint proxy**

```cs
        public byte[] DownloadFile(string url)
        {
            var restUrl = $"{_siteUrl}/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/{url}')/$value";
            var request = CreateBaseRequest("GET", restUrl);
            request.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", _formDigest);

            WebResponse fileResponse = request.GetResponse();
            var input = fileResponse.GetResponseStream();

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                input.CopyTo(ms);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Thank you in advance for any help. Of course, I've googled my problem, but without result.

Comment: your download  file Api seems having issue. use Download.aspx url and get the Byte and Return like below
http://<site URL>/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=<site URL>/library/folder/fileName.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your Core app try this.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("<file url string>"));
return File(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), "<Content type>", "<download file name>");
```